# Difficulty in creating a good schema in mongodb

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Front end developers use  **Hex code** for writing colors in `CSS` that the conventional way of writing colors. I am creating a project that stores these **Hex code** and the conventional name of colors. So when one types the convention name of the color , it brings out the hex code .

I am using mongodb for my database and mongoose as a framework and while creating a schema for my HEX code i encountered difficulty. How do i make my schema able to store numbers and strings in the same class?
For example:

> const colorStringSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name : String
> });

I want the name to be able to accepts strings and number since HEX code is a mixture of numbers and letters. For example:

- `#444fr`
- `#Ddd54`

Comment: There isn't an issue as a String can contain numbers and letters.

Comment: There's a mistaken assumption here: hex codes are a **string** representation of numbers, representing them as a sequence of alphabetic and numeric digit characters. Store then as the strings they are.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be wrong to store the HEX code in a string attribute, but the HEX code examples you used aren't valid *(#444fr #Ddd54)*.

My advice is for you to continue storing it as string.

If you're using javascript to change the color of your element, here is how you can set it as a HEX string:

1. Here in this Stackoverflow page, press F12
2. Go to console
3. Type:

```
var el = document.getElementById('content');
el.style.backgroundColor = '#1a2e3c';
```

4. See the magic happening. The background changes to blue.

The color is changed using HEX as string.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any more doubts :)